# Drupal 7 stopped working 500 internal Server error

Tags: 7, debugging

For some reasons, my site stopped responding today, Error

> The www.mysite.com page isn’t working
>
> www.mysite.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR
>   500

I understand there are many reasons for 500 error and it hard to know what exactly happend, I had a look into server log and notice this error

> [Wed May 11 10:31:27 2016] [warn] [client x.y.z] mod_fcgid: stderr:
>   PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/pro/includes/common.inc on line
>   5106.

Looking into common.inc

```
function drupal_json_encode($var) {
  // The PHP version cannot change within a request.
  static $php530;

  if (!isset($php530)) {
    $php530 = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=');
  }

  if ($php530) {
    // Encode <, >, ', &, and " using the json_encode() options parameter.
    return json_encode($var, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
  }

  // json_encode() escapes <, >, ', &, and " using its options parameter, but
  // does not support this parameter prior to PHP 5.3.0.  Use a helper instead.
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/json-encode.inc';
  return drupal_json_encode_helper($var);
}
```

Line 5106 =   return json_encode($var, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);

Comment: What happens if you remove the line above temporarily (the comment)? If this just "happened", without you changing anything, it'll be a change your host has made to the web server config

Comment: try restarting apache

Comment: I think it would be more worrying if that fixed the problem @NoSssweat. If restarting apache fixes a syntax error, something's wrong elsewhere. It's probably a BOM issue in all honesty, these things usually are

Comment: Try restarting your database server

Comment: I commented the line still same problem and same complain :/. I am on shared hosting and i can't restart apache or database.

I downloaded my site into my local server and it seems to be working. There is defiantly some problem with the hosting. I contacted them and waiting for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason under PHP selector in Plesk dom and gd was disabled. after enabling those two the site return back to normal.